# Set all node distances for all levels equal in a tikz mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I am making a mindmap with many levels, and wanted to set a constant spacing between nodes for all levels. A simple representation of the code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}

% Packages
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shadings}
    \usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

% Formatting
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,
    text=white,
    grow cyclic,
    every concept/.style={minimum size=1.66cm, font=\scriptsize}]

\node[concept, root concept] {Start}
  child {node[concept] {lvl1}
    child {node[concept] {lvl2}
      child {node[concept] {lvl3}
        child {node[concept] {lvl4}} % end lvl4
      } % end lvl3
    } % end lvl2
  } % end lvl1
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course between `lvl3` and `lvl4`, the inter-node spacing is quite small. I would like to set the spacing between nodes **for all levels and nodes** to be equal. I'm sorry that my Google-foo couldn't find the solution, and I appreciate any help. Cheers!

Comment: Have a peak here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmindmaps%5D+distance

Comment: Thank you for the pointers @MS-SPO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with the help of the comments given above by **@MS-SPO**

you can experiment with the level distance and angles to get the desired result

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}

% Packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

% Formatting
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,
        text=white,
        grow cyclic,
        every concept/.style={minimum size=1.66cm, font=\scriptsize},
        level 1/.append style={level distance=190, clockwise from=-45},
        level 2/.append style={level distance=150,clockwise from=225},
        level 3/.append style={level distance=150,clockwise from=-45},
        level 4/.append style={level distance=150,clockwise from=225},
        ]
        
        \node[concept, root concept] {Start}
        child {node[concept] {lvl1}
            child {node[concept] {lvl2}
                child{node[concept] {lvl3}
                    child {node[concept] {lvl4}} % end lvl4
                } % end lvl3
            } % end lvl2
        } % end lvl1
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solved it! I guess I have to set each level explicitly. Not difficult, but I was curious if there was a "global" solution. Thank you @js bibra !